# optimize large Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an application software. For db, I am using Mysql. Some tables have huge data.The table is showing overloaded. That time from Mysql `optimize table`  option I am optimizing the table.

But I want to know - are there any mysql query by which I can optimize full database from my code....

Comment: You should provide your DB schema. Meanwhile, you want to hear about indexing.

Comment: Yeah index your data!

Comment: @moonwave99 Yes, I have already used indexing.

Comment: @ripa If your database is properly indexed for your queries it should run efficiently will thousands of millions of records; just because you have indexes, doesn't mean they're the right indexes. Have you tried using EXPLAIN to see how efficiently the queries are being executed?

Comment: @ripa just provide your DB schema, and the amount of rows per table [in case such number is immense] - you can use [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes , also tried EXPLAIN. Actually the problem is, in db - full contents of document are storing. So sometime that tables are overloaded.

Comment: Whatss your DB Engine?

Comment: You mean you're storing Word or Spreadsheet of PDF contents in your database... not always sensible, but perhaps switching to [SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or other indexing/search might help

Comment: @MarkBaker I never tried SOLR. will think about this. If possible will use.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need the read the following article on how to optimize your database and table maintenance

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using Engine=MyISAM, you should change to InnoDB.
- Even with MyISAM few, if any, tables benefit from `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.
- It is even rarer for an InnoDB table to benefit.

Please provide the reason for thinking you need to Optimizer.

To iterate though all tables in a Database:

- There is a way to discover all the tables from `infromation_schema.TABLES` and generate the commands -- either using SQL or using PHP.
- A Stored Procedure could encapsulate the data, so no PHP code is even needed.

Comment: It's a 10 year old question, i would bet they have moved on ;)

Comment: @Evert - Valid point.  But I am appalled at how many times users reference 10-year-old Answers or blogs.  When I find out of date info in Questions or Answers (especially my own), I comment or edit.

Comment: @RickJames You're most welcome for Your great answer for this old question.